# PHP stops execution when it reaches a line of code

Tags: php, unix, datetime, epoch

I'm working on a PHP script for Wordpress and I'm making an API call to our system and it includes a .Net to Json formatted DateTime string. Using regular expressions I have stripped it down to the seconds since the Unix Epoch. As I understand, I should be able to then create a DateTime object from that using DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $time); but the script ceases its execution when it encounters it (it executes everything up to that point). I wrapped it in a try/catch but even that's not being executed, it just simply 'dies', I guess.

What's going on here?

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $post->discussion->posttime, &$ms);
$ms = $ms[0];
var_dump($ms[0]);
$time = substr($ms[0], 0, strlen($ms[0]) - 3);
var_dump($time);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $time);
//Nothing after the above line is executed
var_dump($date);
...
```

Output to the page looks like:

```
string(13) "1332244919776" 
string(10) "1332244919"
```

Nothing I put after the DateTime line is displayed (or as far as I can tell, executed). I've used valid Unix Timestamps from online and it still doesn't work. I've tried other formats as well ('Y-m-d') with matching date string formats and none of them have worked. Creating a regular 'now' DateTime object using new DateTime(); works though.

Comment: Add this line before anything else: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`. Then run your script and let us know the output.

Comment: Yes, the indirect answer is that you should turn on error reporting and find out what's going wrong. Add the line simplecoder suggested.  You may need to add the line `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a fatal error with error reporting off.

The most likely cause of the problem is that you are using a version of php < 5.3. Support for [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) was added in version 5.3 while the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object was added in version 5.2.